# "comma" and urlencoding PHP

Tags: php, url, urlencode

On my site, a user can enter text in a field called "Description". I can get whatever text was entered by performing a query and returning this as `$description`. I eventually want to use this information to build a URL. I am running into issues if the user enters a "," in part of the text. As an example, let's say the user entered `"test description, test description"`.

`$description` will return as: `"test%20description,%20test%20description"`

Running `urlencode($description)` results in: `"test+description%2C+test+description"`

This is okay for the `"test+description"` part, but not the `%2C`. Ultimately what I am asking is, how can I instead return: `"test+description,+test+description"`

Comment: This is not very clear. What exactly do you think `urlencode()` does, and why do you think it should leave the comma alone?

Comment: a comma should be encoded in the url - so um what's the problem?

Comment: Why is it a problem that it's encoded? The server that receives the URL should decode the URL, so it will get the original comma.

Comment: urlencode() would eventually allow me to use this text as a query string in a url. For my purposes, it is necessary that the comma remain as is. I never said urlencode() should leave the comma alone, I asked for a strategy in how to leave it alone, which is exactly what @subzeta has done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, urlencode encodes the comma character as a %2C in hexadecimal notation, and that's something you cannot change:
http://www.obkb.com/dcljr/charstxt.html

If you don't want that comma to be encoded I guess you should encode all except commas:

```
str_replace('%2C', ',', urlencode($description));
```

Comment: yes, but commas should not be in the url according to section 2.3 of RFC 3986:

*"Characters that are allowed in a URI but do not have a reserved purpose are called unreserved. These include uppercase and lowercase letters, decimal digits, hyphen, period, underscore, and tilde.*

Comment: You are completely right, but maybe he needs it for some additional purpose before building the final url.